# Secure or not secure URL PHP check

Tags: php

I'll try to make a script if the user is redirected to

http://example.com/?url=http://badsite.com

that the script reacts at the URL and displays an echo saying "Not secure", just like the Twitter and Google system, they also check if the URL is harmful.

I've found something, but this isn't what I was seaching for. Google couldn't help me, it gave me all vague answers.

```
<?php
$badsite = "http://badsite.com";
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($host == $badsite) {
    echo "Secure, redirecting you";
} else {
    echo "NOT SECURE";
}
?>
```

It isn't working as it should, it always displays "Not secure", while the link is secure. I think there's a error somewhere, but I need help fining it.

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$badsite = "http://badsite.com";
$host = $_GET['url'];

if($host == $badsite) {
    echo "Secure, redirecting you";
} else {
    echo "NOT SECURE";
}
?>
```

Ive tried, but it's still not working :(

Let me make the question a littlebit easier, how can I make it so if the url is

http://example.com/?url=Texthere

that there will be an echo on the page with "this is the page of texthere" and if "Texthere" isn't in the URL, that the echo won't be displayed?

Comment: And your question is now?

Comment: @Rizier123 What's wrong with this script, and if someone has a better script, maybe can they link me to that page?

Comment: *What's wrong with this script* Nothing, what should be wrong? What do you want/need?

Comment: @Rizier123 It isn't working as it should, it always displays "Not secure", while the link is secure. I think there's a error somewhere, but I'm a starter so I don't know where

Comment: @CarlJohnson Try: `$host = $_GET["url"];`

Comment: @user1153551 Well it's a question.

Comment: I edited the question into the question box.

Comment: @CarlJohnson ok I revert close activity. thanks

Comment: @KaiMattern Hi thanks for your help, i've edited my code, but it's not working. Also the post is edited, just so you can see the code

Comment: @CarlJohnson *but it's still not working* What does that mean? Do you get any errors? What output do you get what do you expect? (What is the output of `var_dump($host);` ?)

Comment: @Rizier123 I've added an advanced explanation in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your $host variable and if statement like that:

```
$host = "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($host != $badsite) {
echo "Secure, redirecting you";
}
```

This worked just fine for me (tested).
You need to include http:// into your variable, and your if statement was wrong.